# DISTINCTROW equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

Could you please tell me if there is any equivalent of Access' DISTINCTROW for SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From reading the documentation on distinctrow, it looks like you want an exists clause or (for generally better performance) a join:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.a_id)

SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.a_id = B.a_id
-- corrected, should be inner join here
```

Comment: +1 for reading the docs but your statement about performance of `EXISTS` vs `JOIN` is incorrect.

Comment: I swear I've seen situations where they do differ substantially.  They certainly do generate different execution plans.

Comment: Look at the execution plan for `EXISTS` it is implemented as a join (semi join) anyway and can be hash, merge, or nested loops so there is no reason to expect inner join to be better.

Answer (score -3):

SQL server doesn't support `DISTINCTROW` instead you should use the keyword `DISTINCT`

But the answer that Chris Shain has given gives you what you want.

Comment: Access also has a DISTINCT clause which behaves the same as SQL's. DISTINCTROW is different.

Answer (score -4):

You can just use the keyword `DISTINCT` instead.